# Getting your Amazon EC2 Windows Password with the AWS PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk

How can I retrieve windows server password by using AWS PHP SDK.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GetPasswordData() - AWS SDK for PHP 3.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#getpassworddata):

> Retrieves the encrypted administrator password for a running Windows instance.
>
> The Windows password is generated at boot by the EC2Config service or EC2Launch scripts (Windows Server 2016 and later). This usually only happens the first time an instance is launched.
>
> For the EC2Config service, the password is not generated for rebundled AMIs unless Ec2SetPassword is enabled before bundling.
>
> The password is encrypted using the key pair that you specified when you launched the instance. You must provide the corresponding key pair file.
>
> When you launch an instance, password generation and encryption may take a few minutes. If you try to retrieve the password before it's available, the output returns an empty string. We recommend that you wait up to 15 minutes after launching an instance before trying to retrieve the generated password.